# Можно ли использовать в классе ArrayList set method для удаления и перестановки в начало строки?

Tags: java, arraylist

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    int N = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
    int M = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        list.add(reader.readLine());
    }

    String tmp;
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++){                            
        tmp = list.get(0);
      /*                           
      list.set(0, tmp);Почему нельзя сделать через set method - результат 
                                                        вроде одинаковый?
     */
        list.remove(0);                    
        list.add(tmp);
    }

    for (int n = 0; n < list.size(); n++) {
        System.out.println(list.get(n));
    }
}
```

}

Если можно ссылку полезную, только не в сибирь)))

Comment: Используйте `LinkedList`, он делает то что Вам нужно. У него есть методы которыми можно удалить и получить первый элемент и т.д.

Comment: то, что вы написали, не будет работать так как вы хотите. В строчке `add(temp)` элемент будет добавлен в конец, в не в начало.

Comment: Полезную можно, но лучше в Сибирь. list.remove(0);  - в цикле так делать нельзя. если хотите использовать remove в цикле, пользуйтесь итератором, и вызывайте remove именно у переменной типа итератора, а не у коллекции. А вообще это задача для очереди, а не для массива, коим является ArrayList

Comment: А вообще вместо цикла с перестановками элементов, попробуйте альтернативы. Например,  if (M>N) M=M-N; List<String> subList = list.subList(M, list.size()); subList.addAll(list.subList(0, M)); В переменной subList результат